# I'm having a problem related disk space in nexus when trying to delete old docker image

Tags: docker, nexus

I've faced a disk space problem while trying to publish new docker images from Jenkins to Nexus. I've tried deleting unnecessary docker images but still get the same error. So still unable to publish them.

> WARN [elasticsearch[B53806D8-E678EED6-33AE6D2D-74559435-2CF713DB][management][T#1]] *SYSTEM org.elasticsearch.cluster.routing.allocation.decider - [B53806D8-E678EED6-33AE6D2D-74559435-2CF713DB] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [IkQiINmZTfGaLtZlXK3btg][B53806D8-E678EED6-33AE6D2D-74559435-2CF713DB][/nexus-data/elasticsearch/nexus/nodes/0] free: 2.5gb[0.3%], shards will be relocated away from this node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is about your othe containers. you can use du -h -d 1 /var/lib/docker and you can see diks usage status